# Microsoft Edge browser doesn't render double 'box-shadow inset' properly

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, box-shadow

See the example snippet below of a text using two `box-shadow: inset` as underline.

It renders perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Safari (recent versions).

[image]

But it looks like this on Edge (see the faded line leaking at the bottom of the underline):

[image]

**QUESTION**

Is there any way around this? Or should I just give Edge users what they deserve?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova');

h2 {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  color: rgb(60,128,124);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a.boxShadow {
  color: darkGrey;
  text-decoration: none;  
  line-height: 26px;
  
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px white, inset 0 -4px 0 rgb(60,128,124);
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <a class="boxShadow">Hello gjq box-shadow</a>
</h2>
```

[image]

https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/all/europe/#monthly-201810-201910-bar

Comment: Sorry, what does Edge's market share in Europe have to do with your question?

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's just to illustrate that it's not neglible. I would like for my web to render properly on it. But I don't think it's possible. I tried many things. If it was 0.05% I wouldn't bother with this at all.

Comment: soon microsoft will build its browser based on chrome
I mean its already done but not official

Comment: @CedricGourville I heard! Looking forward to this.

Comment: @cbdev420 Its seems Edge need an extra element https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/ Hope its help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the issue in Microsoft Edge(EdgeHTML). I think it might be due to the different performance of different browser's render engine. Besides, I found a similar [issue report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4390955/), you could also report this issue. The situation of [another issue report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12908991/) is also similar.

You could try to avoid using two inset box-shadow in Microsoft Edge(EdgeHTML) and use the code below as a workaround:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova');
h2 {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  color: rgb(60, 128, 124);
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.boxShadow {
  color: darkGrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 26px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgb(60, 128, 124);
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <a class="boxShadow">Hello gjq box-shadow</a>
</h2>
```